# Server looks for jsp in the wrong directory Spring MVC + Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

In my Spring MVC application I have the next ViewResolver:

```
 @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
```

I have the Controller with two methods:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class CheckPageController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        return "myview";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testagain")
        public String anotherTest() {
        return "myview";
    }
}
```

My .jsp files are in `WEB-INF/view` directory
When I go to `/test`, server perfectly opens `myview.jsp`
When I go to `/test/testagain`, server shows next:

```
Message /test/WEB-INF/view/myview.jsp
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Why does it look for `myview.jsp` in this path?
Why does the path start with `/test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");` to `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");`

Because if you are not adding slash before then it will search in the same directory of the application and it wont find the resource obviously. so it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
```

**Why?**

`UrlBasedViewResolver` which is parent of `InternalResourceViewResolver`, sets `url` of view with this:

```
AbstractUrlBasedView view = (AbstractUrlBasedView) BeanUtils.instantiateClass(getViewClass());    
view.setUrl(getPrefix() + viewName + getSuffix());
```

This is the `url` where `DispatcherServlet` will forward to.

As you don't have a leading `/`, your forward url is relative to current url and it is `/test/WEB-INF/view/myview.jsp` which does not exist.

*Suggested Reading: [What is the purpose of leading slash in HTML URLs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls)*

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, I understood